# Memory Allocation Issues (possible leak) in WPF application, using Pages and TabContol

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks

**Disclaimer:**

I'm having huge issue with memory managment, within my application. They have poped up first in May, 2018, but thanks to various articles on MSDN and here, SO, I was able to reduce the problem, but not really fix it. After I did some reading, testing and coding, I'm comming here, because I need help.

**Application background:**

My app is a sell-management app, for small client. It runs on remote desktops, with quite limited memory, so I need to keep memory usage low. MainWindow, consists list menu, to the right (old-schoolish), after clicking on menu item, new **Page** is being opened as a **RadTabItem** (ib4 you hit me with "Ask teleriks for that", it doesn't matter, I have the same issue with TabItems) content, here is a code sample:

```
    private void KlientDzwoniTab(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        App.StronaGlowna.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;

        try
        {
            if (CheckIfTabIsOpened("Klient dzwoni") == false)
            {
                _nazwakarty = "Klient dzwoni";
                var strona = new KlientDzwoni();
                AddItem(strona, _nazwakarty);

                App.StronaGlowna.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            }
            else
            {
                SelectTab("Klient dzwoni");
                App.StronaGlowna.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        ... catch block and stuff
```

and essential thing, which is AddItem() function:

```
 public void AddItem(Page strona, string header)
    {

        try
        {
            #region Close button region
            var grid = new Grid();


            var c1 = new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) };

            var c2 = new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(21) };


            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c1);
            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c2);



            var button = new RadButton
            {
                Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0),
                Margin = new Thickness(5, 0, 0, 0),
                Width = 16,
                Height = 16,
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
                VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
                Content = "x",
                FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
                Background = Brushes.Transparent,
                BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0),
                Tag = header


            };

            button.Click += Zamknijtab;

            var stringHeader = header.Replace(" ", "");
            stringHeader = stringHeader.Replace(":", "");
            stringHeader = stringHeader.Replace("/", "");
            stringHeader = stringHeader.Replace("-", "");
            stringHeader = stringHeader.Replace(".", "");
            stringHeader = stringHeader.Replace("_", "");

            var textBlock = new TextBlock
            {
                Text = header
            };

            // panel.Name = header;



            grid.Children.Add(textBlock);
            Grid.SetColumn(textBlock, 0);

            grid.Children.Add(button);
            Grid.SetColumn(button, 1);

          #endregion

            var content = strona.Content;

            var itemToAdd = new RadTabItem
            {
                Header = grid,
                Content = content


            };



            var klientDzwoni = strona as KlientDzwoni;
            if (klientDzwoni != null)
            {

                itemToAdd.KeyDown += klientDzwoni.F3KeyDown;
            }

            itemToAdd.SetValue(NameProperty, stringHeader);


            tabControl.Items.Add(itemToAdd);

            tabControl.SelectedItem = itemToAdd;



        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           ...catch stuff
        }


    }
```

Now, user can, obviously, close those tabs, hitting Zamknijtab event:

```
  public void Zamknijtab(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            var listaTabow = tabControl.Items;

            var button = sender as RadButton;

            if (button != null)
            {
                if (button.Tag != null)
                {
                    var stringHeader = button.Tag as string;
                    stringHeader = stringHeader.Replace(" ", "");
                    stringHeader = stringHeader.Replace(":", "");
                    stringHeader = stringHeader.Replace("/", "");
                    stringHeader = stringHeader.Replace("-", "");
                    stringHeader = stringHeader.Replace(".", "");
                    stringHeader = stringHeader.Replace("_", "");

                    var tabs = listaTabow.Cast<RadTabItem>();



                    tab = tabs.Reverse().FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == stringHeader);
                    if (tab == null)
                    {
                        tab = tabs.Reverse().FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == stringHeader);
                    }

                    if (tab != null)
                    {
                        if (button.Tag.ToString().Contains("Zam:") &&
                            !button.Tag.ToString().Contains("podsumowanie"))
                        {

                            NumerZamowienia = stringHeader.Replace("Zam", "");
                            if (App.ZamowieniaCommitGet(NumerZamowienia))
                            {

                                var textBox = new Label
                                {
                                    Content =
                                        "Na zamówieniu są wprowadzone pozycje, czy chcesz usunąć zamówienie?!",
                                    FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
                                    Foreground = Brushes.Red
                                };




                                RadWindow.Confirm(new DialogParameters
                                {

                                    Header = "Potwierdź zamknięcie okna",
                                    Content = textBox,
                                    Closed = OnConfirmClosed,
                                    Owner = App.StronaGlowna,
                                    OkButtonContent = "Tak",
                                    CancelButtonContent = "Nie"

                                });


                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (NumerZamowienia != null)
                                {

                                    var zamowienie = Db.dst_Orders.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Numer == NumerZamowienia);
                                    if (zamowienie != null)
                                    {
                                        ZamowienieId = zamowienie.Id_Order;
                                    }

                                    var pozycje = Db.dst_OrderLines.Where(f =>
                                        f.Order_Id == ZamowienieId && f.Ilosc != null && f.Ilosc > 0);
                                    if (!pozycje.Any())
                                    {
                                        var id = App.GetUserId();
                                        Db.No_Order(ZamowienieId, null, id);
                                    }
                                    tabControl.Items.Remove(tab);


                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tabControl.Items.Remove(tab);
                        }

                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    var typ = tabControl.SelectedItem as RadTabItem;
                    var tabs = listaTabow.Cast<RadTabItem>();
                    if (typ != null)
                    {
                        tab = tabs.Reverse().FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == typ.Name);

                        if (tab != null)
                        {
                            tabControl.Items.Remove(tab);

                        }
                    }
                }               
            }
            else
            {
                var typ = tabControl.SelectedItem as RadTabItem;
                var tabs = listaTabow.Cast<RadTabItem>();
                if (typ != null)
                {
                    tab = tabs.Reverse().FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == typ.Name);

                    if (tab != null)
                    {
                        tabControl.Items.Remove(tab);

                    }
                }
            }



        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
           ... Another catch
```

This one, could've been a little refactored, but well, it is, as it is.

**The Problem:**

**Closing tabs, doesn't release allocated memory to them (like never).**

All my items, opened in RadTabItems are a custom **Pages** (tried it with **UserControl**, same issue) and problem exist to all of them. `KlientDzwoni()` class is a little one, raising memory usage, by, like ~4 MB, but I have much bigger pages, that raise it by 100-200 MB (reporting tools).

Speaking of memory and MB, you might ask, how did I analyze those, so I started with, ofc, Task Manager and it shows, that memory usage raises, every time I open new tab, and it never goes down. After reading [this wonderful post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/268462f3-ec45-4507-996e-70fb1f00d68f/how-to-avoid-memory-leak-when-removing-a-tabitem-with-usercontrol-as-content?forum=wpf), I've downloaded JetBrains dotMemory, and it helped me to detect memory leaks in my application, **BUT it doesn't actually cosider not releasing memory as a leak**.

In my opinion, those pages (like `KlientDzwoni`) are being held somewhere in memory, for some reason and are never released AND not considered as not needed (thus, not being detected as a leak). Here are things I've tried, to fix the problem.

**My Miserable Attempts:**

- Referring to article, mentioned before, I've tried to use `GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);` . It actually helps a little (reduces leak, by ~10-20%), but doesn't fully fix the problem. Also, since it's not recommended to force GC to work, I'm kinda scared.
- BindingOperations.ClearBinding - I thought that this idea is kinda cool. I mean, I don't unbind events and property in my pages, firstly, because I don't have correct event for that (well, there is no Closing event, there is Unloaded on the other hand), and secondly, it's C#, so I expect Dispatcher and GC to do the job for me. Maybe I'm completly wrong about this, and I should unsubscribe all the events and nullify all collections and variables in some event, but, when TabItems, is removed, it's content (Page.Content) is removed, thus, there shouldn't be any event, to unsubscribe, right?
- Nullifying variables and properties, like TabItem.Content, variables, holding page objects, etc. 0 results.
- Using **UserControl**, I mentioned it above, it doesn't help at all.
- Giving up on my beloved framework, which is Telerik (it is not), and using TabItems, instead of RadTabItems, 0 results.

**What was actually unhelpful:**

There are many posts, articles, thesis, about Memory **Leaks** (I'm still unsure if it is a leak) and TabControl probles, but, I believe, they are constructed poorly, so answers are inacurate for few reasons:

- Many answers focuses on "Memory Leak", with ideas how to check if it is a memory leak, or it's not, or it's, I don't know, Apricot. The core of it problem is that, memory is being allocated and is never released. I don't care how do we call that issue.
- Other answers links questions/posts/articles/answers with the same, recurring issues. [This link is being used the most often](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/268462f3-ec45-4507-996e-70fb1f00d68f/how-to-avoid-memory-leak-when-removing-a-tabitem-with-usercontrol-as-content?forum=wpf).

I wasn't able to find actual solution to this issue. It's been posted on SO, on MSDN and in the other places, many times, in past few years, but I've never found OP answer like "thanks guys, the issue was xxx, the fix was to yyy". But there is some kind of pattern - Someone comes with TabItem memory issues, and never leaves with correct answer.

So, can someone, finally, answer question "How to release allocated memory" and end this endless problem?

EDIT 2:

Uploaded sample project here:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ali8Cn1kITEDhEwn-WAEEl04talS
It consists telerik components, but can be replaced with vanilla WPF, to present the same behaviour.

Comment: If you bind itemssource and templated out your tabs then you would have only one content at a time. When you instead add tabitems you have them all in memory.

Comment: @Andy I have no issues with having multiple tabs opened. I just want them to dissapear from memory, when closed.

Comment: I think you're missing my point. 1 tab IN MEMORY from templating. All tabs IN MEMORY when adding. See the difference? 1 being less than many.

Comment: Thank You @Andy, but You might be missing my point - I want 0 tab IN MEMORY, when I close them all. 0 being less than 1.

Comment: Although I find it  unlikely for memory leaks coming from UI, I think may be using 3rd party tools could help https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radtabcontrol/overview2

Comment: Your example app does not appear to have a memory leak. Opening and closing a tab does indeed incrementally increase the RAM usage, but after 3 minutes all of the extra RAM is released. This must be due to a higher generation garbage collection occurring (Generation 1 or 2)

Comment: @MartinGrundy this example app is really simplified. In main app, I have db connections and events on every page I open. After analysis, I found 1 user, that generates 1,5 GB RAM usage...

Comment: @Vanghern I was just pointing out that I was unable to replicate the memory leak with that example which indicates that this is not an issue with the TabControl at all, otherwise this simple example would also demonstate the same issue. As you are creating the controls in code, I would go through your event handlers and ensure you do not have memory leaks due to not unsubscribing event handlers keeping the controls alive.

Comment: @MartinGrundy but, the fact, that memory allocation persists for 3 mins after it's not needed (for simplified example), kind of reflects issues with this controll, isn't it? I mean, it's not so hard to generate 1 GB memory usage for this sample app, which is riddiculous.

Answer (score 1):

After posting this issue on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/06623b70-a3d9-40c8-84c1-05a17892f50c/memory-allocation-issues-possible-leak-in-wpf-application-using-pages-and-tabcontol?forum=wpf), someone actually answered it. So the solution was to, unsubscribe events from button, clear tab item and call GC, here is the code, that fixed my issue:

```
public void Zamknijtab(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var listaTabow = tabControl.Items;
        var button = sender as RadButton;
        if (button != null)
        {
            button.Click -= Zamknijtab;
            var typ = tabControl.SelectedItem as RadTabItem;
            var tabs = listaTabow.Cast<RadTabItem>();
            if (typ != null)
            {
                tab = tabs.Reverse().FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == typ.Name);
                if (tab != null)
                {
                    tabControl.Items.Remove(tab);
                    tab = null;
                }
            }
            GC.Collect();

        }
        else
        {
            var typ = tabControl.SelectedItem as RadTabItem;
            var tabs = listaTabow.Cast<RadTabItem>();
            if (typ != null)
            {
                tab = tabs.Reverse().FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == typ.Name);

                if (tab != null)
                {
                    tabControl.Items.Remove(tab);
                }
            }
        }
        App.main.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
    }
```